# Retrieve the Kth quantile within each group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following DataFrame in Pandas:

```
                                        value
store          code
I1             AS10937               0.018868
               AS12711               0.002250
               AS12890               0.000229
               AS12914               0.000142
               AS12933               0.000532
I2             AP1001-404563         0.021739
               AP1001-404585         0.002503
               AP1001-439869         0.060000
               AP1001-441215         0.083333
               AP1001-445883         0.014493
I3             CW501555              0.009650
               CW501676              0.002222
I4             PB25015               0.000695
               PB25393               0.001806
               PB25571               0.022690
               PB25633               0.000431
I5             YH141208              0.000705
               YH167493              0.001292
               YH23351               0.001841
               YH257455              0.000772
               YH26109               0.004845
I6             RB10043               0.014806
               RB10045               0.023114
               RB10055               0.002543
               RB10065               0.006810
               RB10109               0.018757
```

I would like to retrieve the **bottom** **30% quantile**  of each group (a group is a store). By retrieving this quantile I mean getting the series (i.e. `codes` and `values`) for it (not just the cut-off point). How can I do this?

Comment: How are you going to get percentiles for these data? There are not enough data points in each group surely...

Comment: Thanks @WoodyPride If there aren't enough data for certain indices and for a given K, that's fine (no output for those indices).

Answer (score 1):

OK, so my understanding of quantiles is somewhat limited, so you might need to refine this, but it seems to me what you want to do is the following:

- group the data by store
- for each group find the 0.3 quantile value using the `DataFrame.quantile()` method
- return the data in that group that fall at or below the 0.3 quantile value

To do this, you would group the data and use the `apply` method to apply a function that does the above.

So given this data:

```
import pandas as pd
store = ['I1', 'I1', 'I1', 'I1', 'I1', 
         'I2', 'I2', 'I2', 'I2', 'I2', 
         'I3', 'I3',
         'I4', 'I4', 'I4', 'I4',
         'I5', 'I5', 'I5', 'I5', 'I5', 
         'I6', 'I6', 'I6', 'I6',  'I6'] 
code =  ['AS10937 ', 'AS12711 ', 'AS12890 ', 'AS12914 ', 'AS12933 ', 
         'AP1001-404563 ', 'AP1001-404585 ', 'AP1001-439869 ', 'AP1001-441215 ', 'AP1001-445883 ', 
         'CW501555', 'CW501676', 
         'PB25015', 'PB25393', 'PB25571', 'PB25633', 
         'YH141208', 'YH167493', 'YH23351', 'YH257455', 'YH26109', 
         'RB10043', 'RB10045', 'RB10055', 'RB10065', 'RB10109']      
value = [0.018868, 0.002250, 0.000229, 0.000142, 0.000532, 
         0.021739, 0.002503, 0.060000, 0.083333, 0.014493, 
         0.009650, 0.002222, 
         0.000695, 0.001806, 0.022690, 0.000431, 
         0.000705, 0.001292, 0.001841, 0.000772, 0.004845, 
         0.014806, 0.023114, 0.002543, 0.006810, 0.018757]
DF = pd.DataFrame({'store' : store, 'code' : code, 'value' : value})
```

You might write a function as follows:

```
def quantile_function(df, quantile_point, col = 'value'):
    #Get the quantile value
    quantile_value = df.quantile(quantile_point)[col]
    #Select the data in the group that falls at or below the quantile value and return it
    return df[df[col] <=quantile_value]
```

And then pass that function to `apply` using the groupby object as follows:

```
DF.groupby('store').apply(quantile_function, 0.3)
```

Which results in the following output:]

```
                    code store     value
store
I1    2         AS12890     I1  0.000229
      3         AS12914     I1  0.000142
I2    6   AP1001-404585     I2  0.002503
      9   AP1001-445883     I2  0.014493
I3    11        CW501676    I3  0.002222
I4    15         PB25633    I4  0.000431
I5    16        YH141208    I5  0.000705
      19        YH257455    I5  0.000772
I6    23         RB10055    I6  0.002543
      24         RB10065    I6  0.006810
```

Is this something like what you wanted?