# get pandas dataframe records according to a specific column quantiles

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to get the records of dataframe `df` whose values of column `c` equal to a list of specified quantiles.

for a single quantile this works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
print(df[df['C'] == df['C'].quantile(q = 0.25)])
```

and outputs:

```
   A  C
1  b  2
```

but it looks clunky to me, and also fails when there are multiple quantiles: `print(df[df['C'] == df['C'].quantile(q = [0.25, 0.75])])` throws `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

related to [Retrieve the Kth quantile within each group in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350830/retrieve-the-kth-quantile-within-each-group-in-pandas)

Comment: can you please provide some sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using this way:
All you have to do is keep your desired quantiles, in a list: as shown below:
You will have your result in `final_df`

```
quantile_list = [0.1,0.5,0.4]

final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
for i in quantile_list:
    temp = df[df['c'] == df['c'].quantile(q = i)]
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df,temp])
final_df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)  #optional incase you want to reset the index
```